# How to download an HTML file from Firebase and load in webview?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have been able to load images from Firebase using Glide, but I am not sure how to proceed to load an HTML file from Firebase in my app's webview. I am using Android studio.

```
 storageRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // Local temp file has been created
                // taskSnapshot.getStorage();
     // how to download and show in webview ?
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle any errors
                Toast.makeText(Home_screen.this, "FAILED",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to show the html file content in webview, then it is pretty simple. 
There is **option to generate url for particular file in firebase console**. Once you generated the file url, then use same to load in webview.

```
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view);
     // be cautious before enabling javascript, check security guidelines by google.
    //webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // on page load started, you may show progress spinner to user.
            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view,
            WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            // ERROR handling
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // actions on page load
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

    });
    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: If it is helpful for you, Please accept it as answer. @SandhyaKrishnan